# Prevent users browsing the website with the old URL after rewriting

Tags: php, .htaccess, url, mod-rewrite

I am new to .htaccess, and I am trying to make friendly URLs (or pretty, SEO-friendly URLs). I did the following things on .htaccess:

- Remove .php extensions on all the file. 
 - Rewrite the product details pages as follow:

```
RewriteRule ^product-details/([a-zA-z0-9_-]+)/([0-9]+)$ product-details.php?title=$1&id=$2 [L]
```

However, when I go to the URL bar and type the file name with the .php extension, it still works. I want it to redirect the user to the 404.php page. Also, with the product details page, I type the old URL format, it also works.

Illustrations:

```
index => index.php (Works)

product-details/chair/1205 => product-details.php?title=chair&id=1205 (Works)
```

How to prevent this? Should I use PHP or .htaccess? If so, what is the .htaccess solution? Thanks a lot!

Comment: You can simply redirect your old URL to new in PHP itself? Why to send them to 404?

Comment: @AmitGupta Because I want to hide the .php extensions and formats strictly

Comment: Yes URL extensions will not come when you redirect your old pages to new

Comment: means product-details.php?title=chair&id=1205 to product-details/chair/1205

Comment: @AmitGupta No, but they will know that they typed the URL correctly

Comment: How users come to know about old URL's once you update them in your website? After few days your old URL's will also not crawl by Google even.

Comment: But it is better to send them a 404 error. If you redirect them automatically even if they type index.aspx, product-details.php, .etc, it is not a good practice. I want the URL to be typed exactly correct. Then later on you can classify cases easily.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/161983/discussion-between-webdeg-brian-and-amit-gupta).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

After `RewriteRule`, old URL's will automatically redirect to new URL's. Like if the user will open `product-details.php?title=chair&id=1205` he will automatically redirect to `product-details/chair/1205`

So old .php extension URL's will never work even if someone will try to open them.

And I don't recommend to send old URL's to `404 page` as this will make wrong impression on Users and not good for `SEO`.

Comment: I tried on XAMPP localhost, but it still displays index.php, etc.

Comment: What RewriteRule you added for index.php?

Comment: `RewriteRule ^([^\.]+)$ $1.php [NC]` and it doesn't work on product-details neither

Comment: Add Redirect 301 for that along with RewriteRule

Comment: where should I put it?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/161987/discussion-between-amit-gupta-and-webdeg-brian).